# Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have tried fulltext indexing each individual column like so:

```
ALTER TABLE AHF_orders ADD FULLTEXT(customer_fname);
ALTER TABLE AHF_orders ADD FULLTEXT(customer_lname);
ALTER TABLE AHF_orders ADD FULLTEXT(customer_address);
```

and I have also tried indexing as a group like:

```
ALTER TABLE AHF_orders ADD FULLTEXT indexName (customer_fname, customer_lname, customer_address);
```

then I use this Mysql query:

```
(SELECT customer_fname, customer_lname, customer_address FROM AHF_orders WHERE MATCH (customer_fname, customer_lname, customer_address) AGAINST ('smith'))
```

and I still get this:

```
Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

I would also like to add that THIS query DOES work:

```
(SELECT customer_fname, customer_lname, customer_email FROM AHF_orders WHERE MATCH (customer_fname) AGAINST ('george smith'))
```

but I don't want to search the Match against just one column, I need to do multiple. Thanks
!

Comment: This should work correctly with your multi-column index. Try dropping your single column FULLTEXT indexes. Double check that your multi-column index exists.  What version of MySQL are you using? What access method (MyISAM? InnoDB?) are you using for this table?

Comment: MySQL 5 point something... MyISAM: yes. I just got it to work on one table but not the other

Comment: This is really weird but this is how I got it to work: I added the individual fulltext indexes to the columns that I wanted, then I added a group fulltext index to the same columns. Seems to work, but if anyone can explain why I would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX keysearch
ON tpm_items (name)
```

The code above worked for me. I only fulltext indexed one column. However, I'm not sure how add group fulltext index to the other columns as mentioned by others in the comments.